# java enum confusion

Tags: java, interface, enums

I came across the following java code. Here interface contains two methods out of which only one method is implemented in the enum. It is written that `name()` is implemented automatically. My question is how is it possible? I have not read any rule regarding automatic method implementation in enum before. So what is happening here? Furthermore the code is not giving any type of compile time error.

```
interface Named {
    public String name();
    public int order();
}

enum Planets implements Named {
    Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune;
    // name() is implemented automagically.
    public int order() { return ordinal()+1; }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) is defined in Enum class which satisfies your interface contract so you don't have to define `name()` unless of course you want to override the default behavior.

Answer (score 6):

`enum` has a default method `name()`, that's all.

It, and [others like `values()`, `valueOf()`, and `ordinal()`, come from the Enum class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

Answer (score 2):

All enums in Java implicitly extend [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), which implements the `name()` method.

> public final String name()
>
> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, there are attributes and methods which are pre-defined for types. For enums, the method `name()` and for arrays, the attribute `length` are examples. In your example, the method name() would return "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Every `enum` is dervided from the abstract class `Enum<E....>`. That class implements both `name()` and the mentioned `ordinal()` and some more. Take a look.